# Converting int to RGB. Visualization in PHP and HTML/CSS

Tags: php, css, visualization

I'm trying to visualize a data on a grid with cell values actually represented by color. Red means high and blue means low. I was so naive in thinking that `PHP`'s `dechex()` will help me by simply getting the hexadecimal equivalent of the int and using it as `background-color` in `CSS` (I did apply the necessary padding of zeros for small values).

But it doesn't quite get me what I want. Is there an algorithm that will let me visualize this properly? Red means high, blue means low.

My current code is this:

```
<?php
    $dec = (int) $map[$y][$x]["total_score"];
    $hex = dechex($dec);
    $color = ($dec <= 65535) ? (($dec) ? "00$hex" : "ffffff") : 
                               (($dec <= 1048575) ? ("0$hex") : $hex);
?>
```

Notice what it does:

`ff0000` in decimal is smaller than `ff00ff` but on color, the first will show red and the latter violet. I want red to represent very high decimals and blue very low decimals.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what exactly you want to do, and what you tried. Can you show some examples and the code?

Comment: Re your update: ah, I see. I think one of the "how to do a gradient" type questions on SO should help. This looks promising: [Does anyone have a script to create a horizontal gradient (left to right) using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1174232)

Comment: I did get the right "push" in the link that you presented. But I can't accept comments though. So I think I'll accept the HSL if you do not plan on posting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think RGB is not the very best color model here. I'd go with [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) - supported by modern browsers: `color: hsl(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)` and easily to convert to RGB.

HSL let's you define saturation and lightness of the color and the color itself quite easily. Blue is 240 deg, red is 360 deg so all you have to do is to map "low" to 240, "high" to 360 and all mid-value to 240-360 range.

Answer (score 0):

Replace Red with Green and Remove Green by masking with `0xFF00FF` in order to keep Red and Blue only.

```
$color = $your_decimal_number_you_want_to_colorize; // for example $color is 0x00F777
$color = $color << 8; // color is 0xF77700
$color = $color + ($color & 0x00FF00); // color is 0xF77777
$color = $color & 0xFF00FF; // color is 0xF70077
```

---

Using the code above, if `$a > $b` then `$a` will be more red than `$b`.

Comment: this will convert a number to a color made by only red and blue. and his problem is that for example violet in color is greater than red.